# GUI with dynamically changing background

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, augmented-reality

I'm getting a live stream of images from a camera and I want to build a GUI that involves a few different views, navigable using buttons ("go to page 1", "go to page 3", "back", "next" etc.). During operations the stream of images should be viewed as the background of the application with the different views overlayed on top of it.

I've tried doing it in QT but as far as I can tell I can also change the background image using the style-sheets and obviously saving every image separately means it won't work at real-time.

Is there a way to accomplish this in QT?
Can you recommend any other C++ framework where I might be able to accomplish this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from QWidget and implement paintEvent
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent

To force full or partial redraw of a widget update can be called:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update-3